# Facebook iOS App invite not receieving push notification

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I have implemented Facebook latest sdk for App invite feature in my iOS app. I am able to send the invites to my facebook friends, but my friends does not getting push notifications for it. Although they can see it received in Settings>App>App Invite>... , I read that on some other stack-overflow threads that push notification will only received if user does not installed app before, So I have created two test accounts for FB and tried with that but still no luck.

can anyone please help me to get this understand

Comment: Use FBSDKAppInviteContent

Comment: @keyurbhalodiya: I am already using it, As I mentioned I am getting invites just push notification is not coming through

Comment: It might be the notification settings on the Facebook app itself. It should be under More>Settings>Notifications>Notifications from apps.

Comment: I have tried with that too, but that not worked.

Comment: @ParthPandya, Did you find anything? I am facing same problem